# I got error on mongo db query after enable security on server side

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

[image]

Before security disabled my script is working fine but after enable security, I start getting error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No one will be able to help unless you provide at least error details and the relevant messages from the [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file.

However one thing is obvious: you're using deprecated test elements with an outdated MongoDB client driver. [MongoDB 3.0](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-3.0) introduced new [Async API](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/getting-started/quick-tour/) which is not compatible with current JMeter thread model therefore you might want to reconsider your approach to MongoDB load testing and use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead.

Check out [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article for more details.

Also consider using separate machines for JMeter and MongoDB because both are resource intensive when it comes to high loads and you will get inaccurate results given you have JMeter installed at the same machine as MongoDB

Comment: Thank for your response, how can I connect mongo db with mongo sampler. Here is the error I am getting. { "serverUsed" : "user-data/localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "command eval requires authentication" , "code" : 13 , "codeName" : "Unauthorized"


This error occurred due to the user not being granted the role "read" or "readWrite" .